# Determine branch of origin from bzr blame

Tags: bazaar

I had a complicated change that affected a bunch of files. I don't remember what bazaar branch I wrote that change in. We have a somewhat complicated merge setup, so the branch I'm in now lumps that change in with a lot of other changes. I'd like to do some very similar work so it would be nice to pull the original diff.

I feel like I should be able to use bzr blame. I run this command on one of the files

```
bzr blame --long path/to/file
```

and I find one of the pertinent lines and get something like

```
1107.6.213 dsmith@satie        20091202 |   tinyMCE.init({
```

Can I use that to figure out what branch and revision the original change came from? What do the 6 and 213 stand for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a better overview of your revisions graph using `bzr qlog` and `bzr qannotate` commands from [QBzr plugin](https://launchpad.net/qbzr). Both qannotate and qlog will show you graph of revisions in which your file was changed. You can see then how your original branch was merged in the trunk.

But even without QBzr you can get some hints about your original branch:

1) run `bzr log -r1107.6.213` to see information about this revision. You will see commit message, but also you will see branch nick. Branch nick is usually last part of the path to the branch where commit happens, e.g. for branch path `/home/foo/project/bar/mybranch` the nick will be `mybranch`.

2) revision number `1107.6.213` means that your original branch was forked from mainline revision 1107, it was 6th branch created from this point which merged into the trunk, and 213 is revision since the fork, so in your original branch this revision has number `1107+213=1320`